# How to update a program with a daily changing file name?

Tags: ruby

I have a program that reads in a file and does some parsing to it. The file is generated by another program every night. Due to the ICD the date is part of the file name.

The file name changes every night due to the date change so I am not sure how to have my program change the `fileIn` name to accommodate this.

If the current fileIn is:

```
in20120103out.dat
```

Tomorrow's fileIn is:

```
in20120104out.dat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`strftime()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) method to generate the date portion of the filename:

```
t = Time.­now
filename = "in#{t.strftime('%Y%m%d')}out.dat"
```

And then use the filename variable to open the file as normal.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = Time.now.strftime("in%Y%m%dout.dat")
```

or

```
require 'date'
filename = Date.today.strftime("in%Y%m%dout.dat")
```

`strftime` means *string format for time*. The %-parameters are  placeholder for Year (Y), month (m), day (d). (There are more placeholders, e.g. year without century...)